# Calculate whole columns of Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Following problem: 
I want to calculate a Long-term mean up to a specific row with pandas. I got it running but it seems really slow and I think there should be nicer solutions to that.

I have a pd.df called "Mean_df", could look like this:

```
Index    Day1     Day2    Day3     Day4
1          1       2        2        1
2          3       5        4        4 
3          9       2        5        0
```

I want to create a new DF that gets the mean for each row up to this Day, e.g. for row 1 it would look like this:

```
    Day1   Day2   Day3   Day4
1    1      1.5   2.66   1.5
```

Currently, I am using the following code and it is working, just slow as mentioned.

```
LTM = pd.DataFrame(None, index = Mean_df.index, columns = Mean_df.columns)
for row in range(LTM.shape[0]):
  for col in range(LTM.shape[1]):
    LTM.iloc[row,col] = Mean_df.iloc[row,0:col].mean()
```

As you can see I am iterating through every row and col.

I thought there might be a possibility to calculate the whole column without iterating through all rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.expanding`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) by columns and then `mean`:

```
df = df.expanding(axis=1).mean()
print (df)
   Day1  Day2      Day3  Day4
1   1.0   1.5  1.666667   1.5
2   3.0   4.0  4.000000   4.0
3   9.0   5.5  5.333333   4.0
```